# Setup Proxy and send web URL as local URL , iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, video-streaming

I want to send a web url to a video resource to my other devices on wifi network as a local url from my phone while sharing , I am not sure how I can do this on iOS with some third party library or Proxy. 
Any pointers will be appreciated. I assume this is something simple but I am new to this .

Comment: You can use https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer I made it a long time ago on a project. It's not that simple.

Comment: @Larme thanks will check but I am not sure compete HTTPServer needed